# Determine the period of a curve

Tags: curves, periodic-functions

A curve is expressed with the two equations:

$x=3+\cos(t)$

$y=4\sin(t)$

How can I find the period of this curve? I was thinking to get the period of $y = 4\sin(\arccos(t-3))$ but I'm not sure of that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since each component is periodic with period $2\pi$, the curve is periodic with period $2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks didn't think of that >.< But what if the equations are something like this: $x=at$ and $y = a(1-cost)$

Comment: Then, since the first component is not periodic, the curve is not periodic.

Comment: I understood that it does repeat it self every $2\pi$ but how to prove that $2\pi$ is the period itself? Couldn't it be periodic of a period less than $2\pi$? I am asking in general cases not only in this example

Comment: Oh okay I understand that but I have a question that asks me to calculate the surface limited by the x-axis and one periode of the curve with $x=at$ and $y= a(1-cost)$. So I ignore the $x=at$ and just take the period of $y=a(1-cos(t))$?

Comment: @ScoobyDuh Since the curve is not periodic, the questions doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @FareedAF Because if $T$ is a period of a curve, then $T$ is a period of each of its components. But we know that the period of each component is $2\pi$.